# CKE change blockqoute style

Tags: blockquote

When i use this code in CKE Editor:

```
<blockquote>test
<blockquote>test</blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

can i change this:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTR7.jpg)
to this:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9HO5.jpg)

Problem: The PN Messenger in our CMS reply the last message with blockquote in blockquote. And with several replies this is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Your Code
<blockquote>test
<blockquote>test</blockquote>
</blockquote>

Updated 
<blockquote>test</blockquote>
<blockquote>test</blockquote>
```

Comment: I know this. But the problem is that the messenger system create this. When i reply a private message then is the message in blockqoute. After 3-4 replays i have many blockquote in blockquote. But i dont finde a way to change this via css. And i think there is no way. 

The CKE Editor have a plugin.js for blockquote (_ckeditor/plugins/blockquote). Is there a way to display every blockquote in a new line?

Thanks for help

Comment: @GamerTemplates i added a javascript code for display every blockquote in a new line. have a look my another answer.  var array = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
   array[i].savedContent = array[i].innerHTML;
   array[i].style.margin = 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

You want to display every blockquote in a new line.  Try this

```js
var array = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
   array[i].savedContent = array[i].innerHTML;
   array[i].style.margin = 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   <blockquote>test
    <blockquote>test</blockquote>
</blockquote>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I insert your code here (line 24) Is that correct? But it do not change.

```js
1/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2019, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

( function() {
 function noBlockLeft( bqBlock ) {
  for ( var i = 0, length = bqBlock.getChildCount(), child; i < length && ( child = bqBlock.getChild( i ) ); i++ ) {
   if ( child.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && child.isBlockBoundary() )
    return false;
  }
  return true;
 }

 var commandObject = {
  exec: function( editor ) {
   var state = editor.getCommand( 'blockquote' ).state,
    selection = editor.getSelection(),
    range = selection && selection.getRanges()[ 0 ];

   if ( !range )
    return;
   
   // Rakibul Islam
            var array = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
            for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            array[i].savedContent = array[i].innerHTML;
            array[i].style.margin = 0;
            }
   
   var bookmarks = selection.createBookmarks();

   // Kludge for https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/1592: if the bookmark nodes are in the beginning of
   // blockquote, then move them to the nearest block element in the
   // blockquote.
   if ( CKEDITOR.env.ie ) {
    var bookmarkStart = bookmarks[ 0 ].startNode,
     bookmarkEnd = bookmarks[ 0 ].endNode,
     cursor;

    if ( bookmarkStart && bookmarkStart.getParent().getName() == 'blockquote' ) {
     cursor = bookmarkStart;
     while ( ( cursor = cursor.getNext() ) ) {
      if ( cursor.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && cursor.isBlockBoundary() ) {
       bookmarkStart.move( cursor, true );
       break;
      }
     }
    }

    if ( bookmarkEnd && bookmarkEnd.getParent().getName() == 'blockquote' ) {
     cursor = bookmarkEnd;
     while ( ( cursor = cursor.getPrevious() ) ) {
      if ( cursor.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && cursor.isBlockBoundary() ) {
       bookmarkEnd.move( cursor );
       break;
      }
     }
    }
   }

   var iterator = range.createIterator(),
    block;
   iterator.enlargeBr = editor.config.enterMode != CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

   if ( state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF ) {
    var paragraphs = [];
    while ( ( block = iterator.getNextParagraph() ) )
     paragraphs.push( block );

    // If no paragraphs, create one from the current selection position.
    if ( paragraphs.length < 1 ) {
     var para = editor.document.createElement( editor.config.enterMode == CKEDITOR.ENTER_P ? 'p' : 'div' ),
      firstBookmark = bookmarks.shift();
     range.insertNode( para );
     para.append( new CKEDITOR.dom.text( '\ufeff', editor.document ) );
     range.moveToBookmark( firstBookmark );
     range.selectNodeContents( para );
     range.collapse( true );
     firstBookmark = range.createBookmark();
     paragraphs.push( para );
     bookmarks.unshift( firstBookmark );
    }

    // Make sure all paragraphs have the same parent.
    var commonParent = paragraphs[ 0 ].getParent(),
     tmp = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++ ) {
     block = paragraphs[ i ];
     commonParent = commonParent.getCommonAncestor( block.getParent() );
    }

    // The common parent must not be the following tags: table, tbody, tr, ol, ul.
    var denyTags = { table: 1, tbody: 1, tr: 1, ol: 1, ul: 1 };
    while ( denyTags[ commonParent.getName() ] )
     commonParent = commonParent.getParent();

    // Reconstruct the block list to be processed such that all resulting blocks
    // satisfy parentNode.equals( commonParent ).
    var lastBlock = null;
    while ( paragraphs.length > 0 ) {
     block = paragraphs.shift();
     while ( !block.getParent().equals( commonParent ) )
      block = block.getParent();
     if ( !block.equals( lastBlock ) )
      tmp.push( block );
     lastBlock = block;
    }

    // If any of the selected blocks is a blockquote, remove it to prevent
    // nested blockquotes.
    while ( tmp.length > 0 ) {
     block = tmp.shift();
     if ( block.getName() == 'blockquote' ) {
      var docFrag = new CKEDITOR.dom.documentFragment( editor.document );
      while ( block.getFirst() ) {
       docFrag.append( block.getFirst().remove() );
       paragraphs.push( docFrag.getLast() );
      }

      docFrag.replace( block );
     } else {
      paragraphs.push( block );
     }
    }

    // Now we have all the blocks to be included in a new blockquote node.
    var bqBlock = editor.document.createElement( 'blockquote' );
    bqBlock.insertBefore( paragraphs[ 0 ] );
    while ( paragraphs.length > 0 ) {
     block = paragraphs.shift();
     bqBlock.append( block );
    }
   } else if ( state == CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON ) {
    var moveOutNodes = [],
     database = {};

    while ( ( block = iterator.getNextParagraph() ) ) {
     var bqParent = null,
      bqChild = null;
     while ( block.getParent() ) {
      if ( block.getParent().getName() == 'blockquote' ) {
       bqParent = block.getParent();
       bqChild = block;
       break;
      }
      block = block.getParent();
     }

     // Remember the blocks that were recorded down in the moveOutNodes array
     // to prevent duplicates.
     if ( bqParent && bqChild && !bqChild.getCustomData( 'blockquote_moveout' ) ) {
      moveOutNodes.push( bqChild );
      CKEDITOR.dom.element.setMarker( database, bqChild, 'blockquote_moveout', true );
     }
    }

    CKEDITOR.dom.element.clearAllMarkers( database );

    var movedNodes = [],
     processedBlockquoteBlocks = [];

    database = {};
    while ( moveOutNodes.length > 0 ) {
     var node = moveOutNodes.shift();
     bqBlock = node.getParent();

     // If the node is located at the beginning or the end, just take it out
     // without splitting. Otherwise, split the blockquote node and move the
     // paragraph in between the two blockquote nodes.
     if ( !node.getPrevious() )
      node.remove().insertBefore( bqBlock );
     else if ( !node.getNext() )
      node.remove().insertAfter( bqBlock );
     else {
      node.breakParent( node.getParent() );
      processedBlockquoteBlocks.push( node.getNext() );
     }

     // Remember the blockquote node so we can clear it later (if it becomes empty).
     if ( !bqBlock.getCustomData( 'blockquote_processed' ) ) {
      processedBlockquoteBlocks.push( bqBlock );
      CKEDITOR.dom.element.setMarker( database, bqBlock, 'blockquote_processed', true );
     }

     movedNodes.push( node );
    }

    CKEDITOR.dom.element.clearAllMarkers( database );

    // Clear blockquote nodes that have become empty.
    for ( i = processedBlockquoteBlocks.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
     bqBlock = processedBlockquoteBlocks[ i ];
     if ( noBlockLeft( bqBlock ) )
      bqBlock.remove();
    }

    if ( editor.config.enterMode == CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR ) {
     var firstTime = true;
     while ( movedNodes.length ) {
      node = movedNodes.shift();

      if ( node.getName() == 'div' ) {
       docFrag = new CKEDITOR.dom.documentFragment( editor.document );
       var needBeginBr = firstTime && node.getPrevious() && !( node.getPrevious().type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && node.getPrevious().isBlockBoundary() );
       if ( needBeginBr )
        docFrag.append( editor.document.createElement( 'br' ) );

       var needEndBr = node.getNext() && !( node.getNext().type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && node.getNext().isBlockBoundary() );
       while ( node.getFirst() )
        node.getFirst().remove().appendTo( docFrag );

       if ( needEndBr )
        docFrag.append( editor.document.createElement( 'br' ) );

       docFrag.replace( node );
       firstTime = false;
      }
     }
    }
   }

   selection.selectBookmarks( bookmarks );
   editor.focus();
  },

  refresh: function( editor, path ) {
   // Check if inside of blockquote.
   var firstBlock = path.block || path.blockLimit;
   this.setState( editor.elementPath( firstBlock ).contains( 'blockquote', 1 ) ? CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF );
  },

  context: 'blockquote',

  allowedContent: 'blockquote',
  requiredContent: 'blockquote'
 };

 CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'blockquote', {
  // jscs:disable maximumLineLength
  lang: 'af,ar,az,bg,bn,bs,ca,cs,cy,da,de,de-ch,el,en,en-au,en-ca,en-gb,eo,es,es-mx,et,eu,fa,fi,fo,fr,fr-ca,gl,gu,he,hi,hr,hu,id,is,it,ja,ka,km,ko,ku,lt,lv,mk,mn,ms,nb,nl,no,oc,pl,pt,pt-br,ro,ru,si,sk,sl,sq,sr,sr-latn,sv,th,tr,tt,ug,uk,vi,zh,zh-cn', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
  // jscs:enable maximumLineLength
  icons: 'blockquote', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
  hidpi: true, // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
  init: function( editor ) {
   if ( editor.blockless )
    return;

   editor.addCommand( 'blockquote', commandObject );

   editor.ui.addButton && editor.ui.addButton( 'Blockquote', {
    label: editor.lang.blockquote.toolbar,
    command: 'blockquote',
    toolbar: 'blocks,10'
   } );
  }
 } );
} )();
```